# Calculation of physical address in 8086

Tags: cpu-architecture

I learnt that the physical address is calculated by shifting the segment address (16-bit) left 4 times and adding it with the 16-bit offset address. The memory in the 8086 architecture is 1M.
My question is if the segment register and the offset value both are FFFFH and FFFFH then the result would be more than FFFFH i.e., more than 1M.

### FFFF0

### +   FFFF

### ----------

### 10FFEF

haw is it actually calculated...??

Comment: Your question is fully answered in this article: [High Memory Area (x86)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_memory_area). The actual handling depends on the CPU's mode (Real vs Virtual), and also the memory controller of the motherboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does modular arithmetic, dropping any carries.  So for a segment of FFFF and offset of FFFF, you compute FFFF0 + FFFF = 10FFEF but it "drops" the initial 1, leaving a real answer of 0FFEF.

Comment: does it always drop the most significant digit??

Comment: Yes, but only if there is a "carry" into the sixth place.  If the sum fits in 5 digits, then all 5 will be kept.

Answer (score 1):

The 8086 address bus is only 20 bits wide, which gives a max high address of 0xFFFFF = 1,048,575. It's calculated just the way you did it, but only the low-order 20 bits are used in the memory fetch.

Comment: yeah, but our process may produce more than that upto 10ffef...
how is it handled??

Comment: It *isn't* handled. As I say, only the low-order 20 bits are used. You can generate all the high-order bits you want, but they'll be thrown away. A read of your address 0x10FFEF will actually read the contents of location 0x0FFEF. I don't remember the details, but I don't *think* you get any kind of address check. What does the data sheet tell you?